# How to update the homepage items when dates are picked

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a javascript date range picker with this structure

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function calender(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('D MMM YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('D MMM YYYY'));
        fetchRecords(start, end);
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        "startDate": start,
        "endDate": end,
        "opens": "left"
    }, calender);

    calender(start, end);

    $('#prevMonth').on('click', function() {
        start.subtract(1, 'month');
        end.subtract(1, 'month');
        $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(start);
        $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(end);
        calender(start, end);
    });

    $('#nextMonth').on('click', function() {
        start.add(1, 'month');
        end.add(1, 'month');
        $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(start);
        $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(end);
        calender(start, end);
    });
    
    function fetchRecords(startDate, endDate) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/record/', 
            data: {
                startDate: startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                endDate: endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Records fetched successfully:', response);
                updateRecordsOnPage(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching records:', error);
            }
        });
    }

    function updateRecordsOnPage(recordsHtml) {
        $('#records-container').html(recordsHtml);
    }
});
```

Once I picked the dates it will past the start and end date to the index controller

```
public function index(Request $request) {
      $user = Auth::user();

      $startDate = $request->input('startDate');
      $endDate = $request->input('endDate');

      $startDate = $startDate ? Carbon::parse($startDate)->startOfDay() : now()->startOfMonth();
      $endDate = $endDate ? Carbon::parse($endDate)->endOfDay() : now()->endOfMonth();

      $records = Record::where('user_id', $user->id)
           ->whereBetween('datetime', [$startDate, $endDate])
           ->paginate(14);

      return view('record.index', compact('records'));
}
```

How can update the record list after picking the dates into the homepage below without reload the page

```
<div class="flex items-center datepicker">
     <i class="fa fa-caret-left ml-2 cursor-pointer" id="prevMonth"></i>
     <div id="reportrange" class="flex mx-auto rounded-md border-0 items-center">
          <span></span>
     </div>
     <i class="fa fa-caret-right mr-2 cursor-pointer" id="nextMonth"></i>
</div>
<div class="records" id="records-container">
    @foreach ($records as $record)
          <!-- record list -->
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I have tried updating the record list through Ajax in the date range picker js above by using `updateRecordsOnPage(response);`, but it keeps looping and duplicating my current view until the page crashes. Any solution to make the data lists update after picking the date without reloading the page?